# on click launch whastapp from flutter app in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, whatsapp

I am trying to launch WhatsApp on click by doing this:

```
var whatsAppUrl ="whatsapp://send?phone=+00000000";
  await canLaunch(whatsAppUrl)? launch(whatsAppUrl):Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
    content: new Text("You need WhatsApp to access"),
));
```

This works perfectly fine in android but not in IOS, i will always get the snackBar in IOS

I also tried to change the url to this if its IOS:

```
whatsAppUrl = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+00000‬";
```

But still didn't work.. what is the issue in my url?

**WORKING:**

```
openWhatsApp() async {
    var whatsAppUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=+00000‬";
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      if (await canLaunch('whatsapp://')) {
        await launch(whatsAppUrl, forceSafariVC: false);
      } else {
        await launch(whatsAppUrl, forceSafariVC: true);
      }
    } else {
      await canLaunch(whatsAppUrl)
          ? launch(whatsAppUrl)
          : Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: new Text("You need WhatsApp to access Sara chatbot"),
              ),
            );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was some issue with the url_launcher some time ago, if you have the latest version, you should be able to pass additional parameter forceSafariVC which should be set to false on ios if you want to handle the deeplink, also I think canLaunch should call only the url scheme prefix like so `await canLaunch('whatsapp://')`

source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25991

Comment: thanks alot! i will update my post with the working answer

Answer (score 2):

Try adding permission in ios/Runnes/info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```